# The expression "binary=True" in In embedding using word2vec

Tags: word2vec

What does mean and what is used for the expression expression "binary=True"  in the following line of code:

```py
w2vmodel = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
    'models/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'), 
    binary=True  # <-- this
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The format written by Google's original `word2vec.c` program had an option to write in plain-text or binary. (Essentially, one wrote floating-point values as human-readable decimal strings, and the other as packed 4-byte binary representations which look like line-noise/strange-characters if viewed as text/characters.)

If you want to read such a file that was written in binary mode, you need to specify `binary=True`, or else the file format will be misinterpreted, likely failing with errors. There are no other differences in later behavior once the data has been successfully read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as I am not familiar with programming, can you tell me ,more specifically, what actually does "binary=True", that prevents the file format to be misinterpreted. What is the process behind this instruction.

Comment: Well, with `binary=False` it uses simple Python string-splitting code, expecting input lines like `apple 0.123 -0.74 0.22`. With `binary=True` is reads raw bytes into raw floating-point numbers, expecting 'lines' that I can't even type into a text box here. (Try to view the un-compressed `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin` file in a text editor to see.) You should read the source code in you need even more detail.